# Tag Synonym Request: [Minecraft-Piston] -> [Minecraft-Redstone]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, minecraft

I'm not sure pistons need their own tag, given that to operate a piston, you'll need redstone. Minecraft-Piston is a subset of Minecraft-Redstone.

Counter-thoughts?

Comment: If we group pistons with redstone, perhaps we should edit the tag wiki to include restone peripherals? e.g. "opens doors, switches tracks, detonates tnt, and toggles pistons"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On principle I'd have disagreed, but 5/6 piston questions also have the redstone tag.

Tags merged, synonym made.

Answer (score 1):

[I agree](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1296950#1296950).